# Working with findall and append

Tags: prolog

I'm stuck. Can someone tell me what I have wrong in my predicate?

```
sizeNet([H|T],L,user,_):-
    findall( Y, fullfriend(H,Y,L,user), LR),
    append( L, LR, LF),
    sizeNet (T, LF, user, LF).

sizeNet([],_,_,_).

fullfriend(userH,Y,L,user):-
    (
     relation(Utilizador,Y)
    ;
     relation(Y,userH)
    ),
    \+member(Y,L),
    Y \== user.
```

If I write

```
?-sizeNet([jon,soldado],[jon,soldado],jony,LF).
```

My `LF` is empty but if I debug, before end the predicate LF have all information I need, but at the end all information is gone. How I can stop recursion and return the information for `LF`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems, but recursion is already correctly stopped when reaching the end of list.

To properly construct and report LF to caller, I suggest

```
sizeNet([H|T],L,user,LTot):-
    findall(Y, fullfriend(H,Y,L,user), LR),
    append(L, LR, LF),
    sizeNet(T, LF, user, LTot).
sizeNet([],L,_,L).
```

Note: `sizeNet (T, LF, user, LF).` is a *syntax error* in most Prologs - no space allowed between functor and arguments list' opening parenthesis